# is Collection a Laravel instance or PHP instance?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

is `collection` a laravel instance or `PHP` instance.
I always hear people say a Eloquent return a laravel collection so I want clearance on this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections - *"The `Illuminate\Support\Collection` Class ..."*

Comment: Don't know, if this answer will be satisfying, but in Laravel, a collection is a specific type of PHP Collection, extended by additional functions, and finally, to your question, it is always a PHP instance...

Comment: @Bart hmm, a "PHP Collection"?  Do you mean it extends the PHP Collection Interface?  If so, that's not entirely accurate since Laravel's collection does not implement the PHP Collection interface.  It does implement most of the interfaces in the Collection interface, but not all of them.  Either way, i agree that it's always a PHP instance.
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-collection.php

Comment: @MMMTroy you are correct about that, but I was trying to provide a simple answer to the question, to understand the basic idea of a collection, especially in Laravel...

Answer (score 0):

The Collection class in Laravel is a part of the Laravel framework.  Therefore, if you attempt to use the Collection class in a pure PHP project (without the use of Laravel) you will not be able to use the Collection class by default.

You can make use of the Collection class without using all of Laravel.  You'll see it's part of the Illuminate/Support components on github.  https://github.com/illuminate

There are also composer packages that will install the Collection class for you all on it's own.  https://github.com/tightenco/collect.  So, I don't think it's correct to say it's a "Laravel Instance", but unless you install it on your project, you won't have access to the class without Laravel.

Laravel makes use of a lot of components that Laravel did not write on it's own.  Symphony, is a major example of this.